# How do I edit the permissions that Adobe Media Server creates directories with?

Tags: linux, permissions, adobe-media-server

OS: CentOS 6.6 AWS-provided AMI found [here](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00IGJMIOI)

I'm using Adobe Media Server 5.0.7.

I have my application set up so that when a user records a video to the server, it goes into its own directory.

If this directory does not exist, it is created automatically by AMS. The problem is that this new directory is created with a permission level that prevents my other app from reading and accessing objects inside of it.

How can I tell AMS to create directories with a permissions level that I specify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing the `Mask` property of `Server.xml` will do it. I set it to `000`, and it worked.